# AngularJs - Add Glyphicons along with data in option of select box having multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am using a select box with **multiple** attribute true. I want to add trash Glyphicon icon in front of my text in Options.I tried some of the method mentioned below:

**Option-1**

```html
<select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="selectData" multiple>
      <option value="option1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

**Option-2**

```html
<select id="mySelect" data-show-icon="true">
  <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery'></i>">-</option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-leaf'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-music'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-send'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></i>"></option>
</select>
```

Please let me know if anyone has any solution to this.

Comment: Standard HTML <select> doesn't support icons inside options. Try using Bootstrap button dropdown. Or you can design your own list with <ul> & <li>.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tag inside a select box. Instead, you can use the Unicode representations

For `bootstrap`

Here's a list of the icons with their Unicode:

[Bootstrap Unicode cheat sheet](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/)

Try this

```
<select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="selectData" multiple>
  <option value="option1">&#x2709; Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">&#xe002; Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">&#xe008; Option 3</option>
</select>
```

For `fontawesome`

Here's a list of the icons with their Unicode:

[Fontawesome Unicode cheat sheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

Try this

css

```
select {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'Second Font name'
}
```

html

```
<select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="selectData" multiple>
  <option value="option1">&#xf2ba; Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">&#xf061; Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">&#xf106; Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Hope it works well.

Comment: Thanks, @laktherock I tried the solution you mentioned but it's not working getting a question mark icon instead of trash icon. And some cheat code is not working. Can you help me with some other suggestion?